# juju spends bootstrap-timeout with a final message it cannot find /var/lib/juju/nonce.txt

Tags: juju, maas

1. I build two VMware's machines. First one with MAAS, second one with a fresh installation from MAAS. Region controller was installed with Ubuntu 12.04 distribution, and upgraded (. Node computing was installed from MAAS with Quantal 12.10. Juju was installed and upgraded to 1.18 (from `ppa:juju/stable` repository). MAAS was upgraded from `cloud-archive:tools`  repository.
2. In debug mode, I got how Juju connects to node. Then I run the same instruction:

   ```
   ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -o "PasswordAuthentication no" -i /home/lliurex/.juju/ssh/juju_id_rsa -i /home/lliurex/.ssh/id_rsa ubuntu@ucc-nodo1.master /bin/bash
   ```

   It worked (with and without `/bin/bash`).
3. When Juju spends all `bootstrap-timeout` tells it has not found `/var/lib/juju/nonce.txt` file. It's true, it doesn't exist. It doesn't mind if you put a timeout of 1800, 3600 or 72000, it always finishes the same.

Comment: This looks like the following bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/+bug/1314682

Answer (score 1):

Can you confirm that all of the machines you have registered in MAAS are

1. Powered off
2. In the Ready state
3. Configured to PXE boot (e.g. Netw
   # use-default-secgroup specifies whether new machine instances
   # should have the "default" Openstack security group assigned.
   #
   use-default-secgroup: trueork boot)

It sounds like you might be hitting an issue where Juju is connecting to a machine that hasn't been booted through MAAS (and therefore missing out on some crucial initialisation code).